# how to cluster curve with kmeans?

Tags: math, cluster-computing, data-mining, cluster-analysis, probability

I want to cluster some curves which contains daily click rate.
The dataset is click rate data in time series.

```
y1 = [time1:0.10,time2:0.22,time3:0.344,...]
y2 = [time1:0.10,time2:0.22,time3:0.344,...]
```

I don't know how to measure two curve's similarity using kmeans.
Is there any paper for this purpose or some library?

Comment: Are the time series the same length? If so, you could just try it directly. If not, you probably want to do [kernel k-means](https://sites.google.com/site/dataclusteringalgorithms/kernel-k-means-clustering-algorithm) using, say. the [dynamic time-alignment kernel](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips14/AA20.pdf) or similar.

Comment: @Dougal   the dateset's length is not equal, maybe y1 contains 40 points ,y2 contains 29points.

Comment: Can you clarify how the datasets are structured? Initially I thought they were the click-rate per time period (say, every 10 minutes), but if they have different sizes, that can't be it. It doesn't seem to be a log either - so how is time1, time2 determined?

Comment: And I assume what you are trying to do is group/aggregate items with similar "click rate seasonality" patterns, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

For similarity, you could use any kind of time series distance. Many of these will perform alignment, also of sequences of different length.

However, k-means will not get you anywhere.

K-means is *not* meant to be used with arbitrary distances. It actually does not use distance for assignment, but least-sum-of-squares (which happens to be squared euclidean distance) - aka: variance.

The mean must be consistent with this objective. It's not hard to see that the mean also minimizes the sum of squares. This guarantees convergence of k-means: in each single step (both assignment and mean update), the objective is reduced, thus it must converge after a finite number of steps (as there are only a finite number of discrete assignments).

**But what is the mean of multiple time series of different length?**

Comment: Kernel k-means is a well established technique that works just fine. The math work out such that you don't need to explicitly calculate means in the underlying RKHS (a good thing, since it might be infinite dimensional). Of course, this means you don't get an explicit representation of cluster means out, but you do get cluster assignments and can assign new points to the selected clusters as well.